# $(1+x)^a$ is bounded by $b\cdot x^a$ if $x>1$

Tags: inequality, newton-series

If $a,x\in \mathbb{R}$, I want to prove that $(1+x)^a$ is bounded by $b\cdot x^a$ if $x>1$, where $b$ is a constant independent of $x$. I believe that Newton bynomial is somehow implicit in the proof I have to do. This is because, if $a\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
(1+x)^a=\sum_{i=0}^{a}{a\choose i}x^{i}.
$$
So,
$$
(1+x)^a=\sum_{i=0}^{a}{a\choose i}x^{i}\leq b\cdot x^{a}
$$
where $b=\sum_{i=0}^{a}{a\choose i}$.
Nevertheless, my $a$ is not neccesarily entire.
So, my attempt has been to use the floor function of $a$ in some way... For example, by saying that $(1+x)^a\leq (1+x)^{\lfloor a\rfloor +1}$ and applying Newton to the upper bound. But, I am not arriving to my desire fact.

Any advice will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If x>1, then 1+x< 2x so $(1+x)^2 < (2x)^a = 2^a x^a$. Set $b=2^a$ when $a>1$.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Wouldn't it also be your argument valid for $0\leq a\leq 1$?

Comment: Yes. It would be. I must have put 1 by accident there.